# Error: Cannot match any routes when using router outlet name in Angular

Tags: angular, router-outlet

I'm using angular 6 and I want to create modal with route, to do this i use router outlet named but when i try to go on the route of the modal an error message is coming :

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL
>   Segment: 'profile' Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment:
>   'profile'

My 2 router outlet are in the same location

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: LayoutComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard, AuthorizationGuard],
    canActivateChild: [AuthenticationGuard, AuthorizationGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        redirectTo: 'deals',
      },
      {
        path: 'deals',
        component: DealsComponent,
      },
      {
        outlet: 'modal',
        path: 'profile',
        component: ProfileComponent,
        data: {
          title: 'My Profile',
          sidebar: {
            category: 'profile',
            text: 'My Profile',
            icon: 'person',
          },
        }
      },
```

I'm using `[routerLink]="['', {outlets: { modal: 'profile' } } ]"` to go on the link.

I made a working exemple of the issue : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-asicvf

Do someone can help me pls? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would have used an array for the `modal` object

```html
<a [routerLink]="['', {outlets: { modal: ['profile'] }} ]">LINK</a>
```

You should also change the order of your children routes and put the `redirectTo` at the end of the array because it will match all your routes before Angular can read the others.

---

Actually, your route is not well formatted. You should have all your routes at the same level and not use the `children`property of your main route. Something like:

```js
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: AppComponent },
  { path: 'deals', component: HelloComponent },
  {
    outlet: 'modal',
    path: 'profile',
    component: Hello2Component,
    data: {
      title: 'My Profile',
      sidebar: {
        category: 'profile',
        text: 'My Profile',
        icon: 'person',
      },
    }
  },
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    redirectTo: 'deals',
  },
];
```

I updated your stackblitz with the correct solution [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oednch)

Comment: Thanks but didn't work :(
Do you have any other ideas about why my route is not recognizes?

Comment: @BaptisteGoudey please provide a working example of your issue

Comment: @BaptisteGoudey I updated my answer with the correction of your issue

Comment: Thanks i can get your solution but the things is i'm doing my routes as children cause my main route include the guard
It's really not possible as children ?